# How to find the determinant of the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> if $\det \begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix} = 1$
>
> then $\det \begin{bmatrix}a - 6g&7b - 42h&c - 6i\\d&7e&f\\g&7h&i\end{bmatrix} = ?$

Yeah, I have no idea how to solve this nor do I know what is going on in the first row??

Here is how the problem is presented to me, I tried my best to copy it.

> [image]

Comment: Multiply the second column by $7$ and then add $-6$ times third row to the first one. What do these operations change in terms of determinant?

Comment: What am I trying to do here? Put the second matrix in RREF? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\det \begin{bmatrix}a - 6g&7b - 42h&c - 6i\\d&7e&f\\g&7h&i\end{bmatrix}=\det \begin{bmatrix}a &7b&c\\d&7e&f\\g&7h&i\end{bmatrix}+\det \begin{bmatrix}- 6g& - 42h& - 6i\\d&7e&f\\g&7h&i\end{bmatrix}$

by the multilinear property, now the second determinate is $0$ because the first and the third row are linearity dependent; so

$\det \begin{bmatrix}a &7b &c \\d&7e&f\\g&7h&i\end{bmatrix}=7 \det \begin{bmatrix}a &b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix}=7$

Comment: Can you explain steps??????

Comment: @Shammy He's using linearity in the first *row*. The first row splits up as $(a-6g,7b-42h,c-6i) = (a,7b,c) + (-6g,-42h,-6i)$.

Comment: I applied the properties of determinate to the rows

Comment: how is the second determinate = 0 ?????????????????

Comment: because the first row is $-6$ times the third row, so they are linearly dependent, then the determinant is $0$.

Comment: do you mean to say *linearly dependent*

Comment: Yes I'm sorry! it's a typo :)

Answer (score 2):

I think they mean $\begin{pmatrix}a-6g & 7b -42h & c-6i\end{pmatrix}$ for the first row.

**Hint**: The determinant is a *multilinear* function of its columns.

For instance: $$\begin{align} \det\begin{pmatrix}a-6g&7b-42h&c-6i\\
d&7e&f\\
g&7h&i
\end{pmatrix} &= 7\det\begin{pmatrix}a-6g&b-6h&c-6i\\
d&e&f\\
g&h&i
\end{pmatrix} \\ &= 
7\left(\det\begin{pmatrix}a&b-6h&c-6i\\
d&e&f\\
g&h&i
\end{pmatrix}
+
\det\begin{pmatrix}-6g&b-6h&c-6i\\
0&e&f\\
0&h&i
\end{pmatrix}
\right)\\ &= \cdots
\end{align} $$

**Edit**: It's actually smarter to use a row operation! See Gianluca's answer.

Comment: Yea, and what am I supposed to do with that? lol

Comment: @Shammy Well for instance you can decompose the determinant of the sum of columns into sums of determinants, and pull out scalars like the $7$ that appears everywhere in the second column...

Comment: So do I need to put this in RREF by doing column operations?

Comment: @Shammy I started it for you. Do you see the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

The matrix is supposed to be

$$\begin{pmatrix}a-6g&7b-42h&c-6i\\
d&7e&f\\
g&7h&i
\end{pmatrix}$$

Hint: This matrix can be written in terms of the original matrix by manipulating the rows and columns.

Comment: So I'm supposed to write it in terms of the original matrix?

Comment: @Shammy Yeah.  Have you been taught about row and column operations and what they do to the determinant?

Comment: I know you can do row operations but can you just show me one example so I can do this problem. I need just an exxample to mimmic